# Use a flag in a Backbone Model but not as a property (that gets saved)

Tags: backbone.js

So what I'm trying to achieve is when the user wants to edit/view an item (the Model), I send them to a URL, create a new Model instance and call .fetch on it before loading up the relevant view and handing it the new Model.

For various reasons, I need to know whether the user is editing or viewing the item (the Model), so my first attempt was this:

```
app.Models.Quote = Backbone.Model.extend({

    idAttribute: 'Number',

    initialize: function() {
        this.editMode = false;  
    },

    url: function() {
        return app.Settings.apiUrl() + '/quotes/' + this.id;
    }

});
```

So in various places in the view/edit View, I could do:

```
if(this.model.editMode){ //foo }
```

However this doesn't seem to be working at all, ie. the editMode isn't found (undefined).

What are people's general solution/advice for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quick example that this property is working : http://jsfiddle.net/damian0o/u9rrh/

Make sure that this is your view instance by adding something like

```
var self = this;
```

or using undersocore method

```
_.bindAll(this,"");
```

in view initializing method

Answer (score 0):

Try adding editMode as a property of the Model.  You can now do this.model.editMode and inside your model, you can refer to editMode as this.editMode.

```
app.Models.Quote = Backbone.Model.extend({

    idAttribute: 'Number',

    editMode: false, // this initializes the value to false   

    initialize: function() {
        //this.editMode = false;  
    },

    url: function() {
        return app.Settings.apiUrl() + '/quotes/' + this.id;
    }

});
```